# Kafka connect source for JDBC - poison pill, bad message, error handling issues

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

- I have some data stored in a postgres table.
- Each row has data that is serialized using Avro.
- I have created a Kafka connect source connector that reads rows and sends them to a topic with the same Avro schema. The topic has `confluent_value_schema_validation` as true.
- This works well, but if I insert a poison pill message into my postgres table, then the connector simply refuses to move forward. One solution is manual intervention to move the offsets forward so that the bad message is skipped. The other solution is setting `confluent_value_schema_validation` to false so that any message can be added to my topic.
- I tried the configs below but nothing happens.

```
"errors.tolerance": "all",
"errors.retry.timeout": 500,
"errors.retry.delay.max.ms": 100,
```

- My question - How can I make the Kafka Connect JDBC source connector ignore errors and move forward with the good messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I make the Kafka Connect JDBC source connector ignore errors and move forward with the good messages?

You can't, currently (January 2021).

The error handling in Kafka Connect will deal with errors at the transform and serde level, but errors from the connector itself reading records from the database will not be dealt with under the same mechanism.

As well as manually moving the source connector past the problem record you could consider an approach by which you ingest the raw feed from the table (with no schema validation) into one topic and then write a Kafka Streams app to read the data from this raw topic and write it to the target one, applying schema validation on the way and handling bad messages at that point.